# Negative mathematical expression coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I only create this:

[image]

With this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  ultra thick,
  y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{sqrt(#1)}},
  y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{pow(#1,2)}}
  ] 
    \addplot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (0.3,0)
    (0.44,0.00016)
    (0.45,0.00045)
    (0.49,0.00071)
    (0.5,0.001)
    (0.51,0.00139)
    (0.54,0.00176)
    (0.56,0.00214)
    (0.57,0.00243)
    (0.61,0.00279)
    (0.63,0.00327)
    (0.64,0.00386)
    (0.67,0.00433)
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

But I need put negative coordinates, for example: (-0.51,-0.00139)

also I need the red line and words (I,V):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- By setting `axis lines=middle`, both the axis will be placed in the middle, once you add negative coordinates.
- You can add labels using `xlabel=$V$` and `ylabel=$I$`.
- Those labels can be placed at a different position with respect to the axis using `x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west}`.
- Drawing the red line can be done using `\draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0.6, 0)--(axis cs:0.6, 0.004);`. Here I use `axis cs` coordinates, which are coordinates linked to your axis.
- Your last request is not possible. You can not add negative values on the y-axis, since you rescale the axis using a square root. The square root of a negative number is a complex number.

An example where I removed the `y coord travo` stuff and added some negative coordinates.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ 
          axis lines=middle,
          ultra thick,
          xlabel= $V$, ylabel=$I$,
          x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west},
%         y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{sqrt(#1)}},
%         y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{pow(#1,2)}},
          ] 
            \addplot coordinates {
            (-0.48, -0.002)
            (-0.43, -0.0002)
            (-0.3, -0.0001)
            (0,0)
            (0.3,0)
            (0.44,0.00016)
            (0.45,0.00045)
            (0.49,0.00071)
            (0.5,0.001)
            (0.51,0.00139)
            (0.54,0.00176)
            (0.56,0.00214)
            (0.57,0.00243)
            (0.61,0.00279)
            (0.63,0.00327)
            (0.64,0.00386)
            (0.67,0.00433)
             };
         \draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0.6, 0)--(axis cs:0.6, 0.004);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Its perfect!!! Thank you very much for your help